# Which configuration file has higher priority for DNS server settings?

Tags: debian, configuration, dns

For Debian, DNS nameservers can be set both in `/etc/network/interfaces`  and in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Which file has higher priority for DNS server configuration?

Comment: The former is used in creating the latter: https://askubuntu.com/a/998093/158442

Comment: Software like `dig`, `nslookup` or the `libc` only use `resolv.conf` when working on DNS requests

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the distribution and what other packages are installed.  Since the differences are part of a default install, I'll call it distribution related.

A quick test -

Debian Jessie stays with the `/etc/resolv.conf` even if `dns-name-servers` are set in `/etc/interfaces`.  Even if `/etc/resolv.conf` is empty.

Ubuntu 16.04 server uses the `resolvconf` package, and it over writes the `/etc/resolv.conf` file each time it runs, so putting the `dns-name-servers` entry in `/etc/network/interfaces` is required unless you edit the various `resolvconf` options.